# What is time complexity of my code with this next() ? I assume it is O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity

```
    public int calculateTotalhours(int id) throws SQLException {
    int totalHour = 0;
    try {
        selectTotalhours.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = selectTotalhours.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println("ID is" + rs.getInt("totalhours"));
            totalHour += rs.getInt("totalhours");
        }
        System.out.println("total hour from id " + id + " is " + totalHour);
    }
    
 catch (SQLException e ) {
        
        
    }
    
    
    return totalHour;
    
}
```

Is it correct that my code is O(n) since next() move cursor one by one row(idk how to explain but hopw you get what I mean)

Comment: Yes. But why not just `SELECT SUM(totalhours) FROM whatever WHERE Id = ?` instead?

Comment: I didn't know if It also could do it like that. I am still a beginner.  but thank for showing the easier way :D    @rzwitserloot